# Volume of Region in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider 
$$ S = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; -N-\frac{1}2 \le x \le N + \frac{1}2, |\alpha x-y| \le \frac{1}N \right\}$$

where $N \in \mathbb{N}, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm having a hard time beliveing that $S$ is convex and Area $S > 4$. Can someone please elaborate why?

Thanks.

Comment: So, $N$ and $a$ are fixed - it can be thought of as $S_{N,a}$?

Comment: Yes, feel free to edit that in if you think this makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a parallelogram with edges $y = \alpha x - \frac{1}{N}, y = \alpha x + \frac{1}{N}, x = -N - \frac{1}{2}, x = N + \frac{1}{2}$, hence is convex with area $\frac{2}{N}((N + \frac{1}{2}) - (-N - \frac{1}{2})) = 4 + \frac{2}{N}$.